# template in copy constructor

Tags: c++, templates

Could you please tell me why I am getting the compilation error

```
template<class T> class 'Node' used without template parameters
```

with the following code

```
template<class T>
    class Node
    {
        private:
            T _value;
            vector<Node*> children;

        public:
            Node(T value);
            Node<T>(const Node<T>& node);
            void AddChild(Node<T>* node);
            T getValue();
            vector<Node<T>*> returnChildren();
            ~Node();
    };

    template <class T>
    Node::Node<T>(T value):_value(value)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T value):_value(value)
{
}
```

Try this one.

Comment: that works ! thanks! when do i know where to put the T using this example? is there a rule?

Comment: When 'Node' indicates a type instead of a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you wrote

```
Node::Node<T>(T value):_value(value)
```

You have no template parameter on the class (the first `Node` on that line) but instead have one on the constructor (the second `Node`).  That is incorrect.

Comment: if i do this `template <class T>
Node<T>::Node<T>(T value):_value(value)
{
}`
 it doesn't work either

Comment: As I said, the second `Node` in that line is the name of the constructor, not the name of the class.  The way you declared the constructor is not as a template.  (The class is a template, but the constructor is a non template function of a template class).  So the constructor name should not have a template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `Node` is the template class. When you use that class, you have to use it with template parameters. This does not work :

```
template <class T>
Node::Node(T value):_value(value)
{
}
```

Because the class `Node` is templated and you use it without template parameter.

This does not work neither because you put the template parameters on the function (here the constructor) not the class.

```
template <class T>
Node::Node<T>(T value):_value(value)
{
}
```

This does work.

```
template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T value):_value(value)
{
}
```

You use this syntax only for the class, it differs when you write a function.

**For function.**
Let's say we have this class

```
class MyTemplate
{
    template<typename T>
    void foo(T val);
};
```

You may define the method like that :

```
template<typename T>
void MyTemplate::foo<T>(T val)
{

};
```

But it fails. Clang prints this error :

> function template partial specialization is not allowed

For function you don't need it, you have to write

```
template<typename T>
void MyTemplate::foo(T val)
{
}
```

And if you want to specialize it, you can write

```
template<>
void MyTemplate::foo(int val)
{
}
```

Or

```
template<>
void MyTemplate::foo<int>(int val)
{
}
```

**Declaration :**

When you declare a variable of type Node, you have to use the template parameter too.

```
Node<int> myNode(12);
```